# What is the difference between setting the text of a label to nil or setting it to ""?

Tags: swift, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` , under certain circumstances, I want to leave the label text empty.

One of the ways that occurs to me is:

```
myLabel.text = nil
```

And the other:

```
myLabel.text = ""
```

What is the difference between one form and the other?
Which is better option and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nil` means it has no value. `""` means it is set to the empty string. The displayed output appears the same between the two but they are two separate values with two separate meanings.

It comes down to the whole reason that optionals exist in Swift. Sometimes you need to differentiate between no value (`nil`) and a specific value (any string, including the empty string).

There really aren't many use cases where you would decide to explicitly use `nil` or `""`. It's more common that you have some optional `String` value and you want to set it to a label. Since the `text` property of `UILabel` is optional, you don't need to do things such as:

```
someLabel.text = someOptionalString ?? ""
```

You can simply do:

```
someLabel.text = someOptionalString
```

When reading the value of a label, you can determine if the label has ever been set (`nil`) or it has a specific value.

Comment: As for the layout, has any difference that the label has its text in nil or have it in "" ?